# Feedburner Multilanguage RSS Feeds

Tags: wordpress, rss, globalization, multilingual, feedburner

Does anyone here know how to get Feedburner to burn feeds in multiple languages?

I have a WordPress blog that has posts in two languages and I would like to have feeds for each of these languages too, so that when I publish a new post my followers would receive the post in their language of choose, instead of getting a feed in a language they may not read or understand.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you achieve any solution?

Comment: Yes, @ArnauLacambra. It's long since I've solved this, but didn't remember that I had asked for help here. I've answered my own question now. Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution (or a workaround, maybe). What I did was to setup two feeds for my blog, one for each of the languages avaliable in the blog. So, in the [english version of my blog](http://www.csprogrammer.net/en/), I promote the [english feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/csprogrammer-en), and in the [brasilian version of the blog](http://www.csprogrammer.net/pt/), I promote the [portuguese feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/csprogrammer).